# Epplus - checking if named style already exists before adding it

Tags: c#, .net, spreadsheet, epplus

I have a class `Comparer`, which defines the following:

```
// partial Comparer code
public class Comparer
{
    private readonly Color colorWarning = Color.Red;
    private readonly string SPREADSHEET_RED_WARNING_STYLE = "red warning style";
    private OfficeOpenXml.Style.XmlAccess.ExcelNamedStyle redWarningStyle;
}
```

This class has a method `prepareSpreadsheet`:

```
private void prepareSpreadsheet()
{
    // spreadsheet styles
    redWarningStyle = spreadsheet.Workbook.Styles.CreateNamedStyle(SPREADSHEET_RED_WARNING_STYLE);
    redWarningStyle.Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
    redWarningStyle.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(colorWarning);
    redWarningStyle.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.Black)
}
```

If the spreadsheet file already contains such a named style, an exception is thrown. Can Epplus programatically check if a certain named style already exists in the spreadsheet, and remove it if it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get it working, but not sure if it is the best solution. It does not remove them, only adds if it finds a style with an existing name (cannot guarantee it has the same style):

```
// retrieve a list of styles from the spreadsheet
List<OfficeOpenXml.Style.XmlAccess.ExcelNamedStyleXml> spreadsheetNamedStyles = spreadsheet.Workbook.Styles.NamedStyles.ToList();

// check if it already exists before attempting to add it
if (spreadsheetNamedStyles.FirstOrDefault(namedStyle => namedStyle.Name.Equals(SPREADSHEET_RED_WARNING_STYLE)) == null)
{
    redWarningStyle = spreadsheet.Workbook.Styles.CreateNamedStyle(SPREADSHEET_RED_WARNING_STYLE);
    redWarningStyle.Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
    redWarningStyle.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(colorWarning);
    redWarningStyle.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.Black);
}
```

Comment: Name styles can be created only once per workbook, not per worksheet. If you attempt to create a named style that already exists in the workbook, it throws an exception, "Key [Name] already exists in collection". By default, there is one style named "Normal" that EPPlus provides automatically.